# view included in all files having bootstrap files path not working in diffrent route

Tags: laravel, file, url, routes, include

`Route::get('fullDetail/{productId}','productController@showSingleProduct');`

http://localhost/laravel-ecommerce1/fullDetail/233

file containing bootstrap files path change from

http://localhost/laravel-ecommerce1/bootstrap.min.css

to

http://localhost/laravel-ecommerce1/fullDetail/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your blade template

```html
<base href="/laravel-ecommerce1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.min.css">
```

the assets are linked relatively and the `/` means link from the root